# Growth of $r_k(n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

What is the best known growth bound of $r_k(n)$, where $$r_k(n)=\#\{(a_1,\dots,a_k\in\mathbb{Z}^k:\sum_{i=1}^ka_i^2=n\}?$$ Please provide some reference if known. Thanks.

Comment: Answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72378/representing-a-number-as-a-sum-of-at-most-k-squares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Igor Rivin said, the question was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72378/representing-a-number-as-a-sum-of-at-most-k-squares) for $k\geq 5$ by Greg Martin. For $n$ not divisible by $8$, the asymptotic formula described there remains valid for $k=3$ and $k=4$ as well, but the proof techniques are slightly different. Note that for $k=3$ the singular series can vanish, but only if $r_3(n)=0$. For $n$ divisible by $8$, we have $r_3(n)=r_3(n/4)$ and $r_4(n)=r_4(n/4)$, so one can reduce to the previous case. Finally, for $k=2$ there is an explicit formula based on arithmetic in Gaussian integers.

Bounding the singular series and the error term is a subtler task.

Comment: You can find an explicit, sharp bound on the error term in the cases that $k \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ in my paper ["Explicit bounds for sums of squares"](http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1105.4824).

Comment: @JeremyRouse: Thank you for the valuable comment!